# How to create a ladder script in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d

I tried to create a climb script and found some similar code. I would like to climb with my player on a ladder. I came up with the following:

bool canClimb = false;
    float speed = 1;

```
GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.


void Awake () {
    // Setting up the references.
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
}



void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) { // send in the other collider (should always work)

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") { // used a tag to ID collider as player
        canClimb = true;
        player.rigidbody.useGravity = false;

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) { // send in the other collider (should always work)

    if(other.gameObject == "Player"){
        canClimb = false;
        other.attachedRigidbody.useGravity = true;

    }
}

void Update () {

    if(canClimb == true){


        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z)){

            player.transform.Translate (Vector3(0,1,0) * Time.deltaTime*speed);

        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            player.transform.Translate (Vector3(0,-1,0) * Time.deltaTime*speed);


        }
    }
}
```

The above code will give a red mark on the `useGravity` in the line of `player.rigidbody.useGravity`. I doesn't know how to fix this.

Comment: @bummzack, I update my answer with the script and detailed question

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using? Unity 5 just came out, and they changed the api for a call like `object.rigidbody`

Comment: Yes, I use Unity5. Where should I look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity 5 just came out, and they changed the API for a call like `object.rigidbody`

Specifically, every component shortcut other than `object.transform` has been removed, since the Transform component is the only one that all objects have. All the other shortcuts only applied a fraction of the time.

Now you need to access the Rigidbody component using GetComponent(), like so (C# code):

```
Rigidbody body = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
body.useGravity etc.
```

Comment: I thought that useGravity doesn't work on a 2D object, am I correct?

Comment: oh these are 2D objects, I missed that. I don't see why useGravity wouldn't work there too, but it's going to be Rigidbody2D instead and that may have a different API than Rigidbody.